# Solving quadratic programming using R

Tags: r, machine-learning

I would like to solve the following quadratic programming equation using ipop function from kernlab :

```
min 0.5*x'*H*x + f'*x  
subject to:  A*x <= b   
Aeq*x = beq  
LB <= x <= UB
```

where in our example H 3x3 matrix, f is 3x1, A is 2x3, b is 2x1, LB and UB are both 3x1.

**edit 1** 
My R code is :

```
library(kernlab)
H <- rbind(c(1,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(0,0,1))
f = rbind(0,0,0)
A = rbind(c(1,1,1), c(-1,-1,-1))
b = rbind(4.26, -1.73)
LB = rbind(0,0,0)
UB = rbind(100,100,100)
> ipop(f,H,A,b,LB,UB,0)
Error in crossprod(r, q) : non-conformable arguments
```

I know from matlab that is something like this :

```
H = eye(3);
f = [0,0,0];
nsamples=3;
eps = (sqrt(nsamples)-1)/sqrt(nsamples);
A=ones(1,nsamples);
A(2,:)=-ones(1,nsamples);
b=[nsamples*(eps+1); nsamples*(eps-1)];

Aeq = [];
beq = [];
LB = zeros(nsamples,1);
UB = ones(nsamples,1).*1000;

[beta,FVAL,EXITFLAG] = quadprog(H,f,A,b,Aeq,beq,LB,UB);
```

and the answer is a vector of 3x1 equals to [0.57,0.57,0.57];

However when I try it on R, using ipop function from kernlab library
ipop(f,H,A,b,LB,UB,0)) and I am facing *Error in crossprod(r, q) : non-conformable arguments*

I appreciate any comment

Comment: Please post the R code you used, including where you define `f`, `H`, `A`, `b`, `LB`, and `UB`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be moved to the R forum?

Comment: @Zen, might be you are right ! I didn't know if such a thing exists !

Comment: It looks like you want matrix multiplication in R which is '%*%'

Comment: +1 to @chandler -- your first line of code has those awful primes (apostrophes) which MxxLxx  uses to transpose vectors.  The R-language understands that vectors are rank 1 (colloquially, "one dimension"), and as chandler said, the default `*` operation is element-wise.

Comment: @chandler @CarlWitthoft, The first set of `code` is not R code. OP is not actually performing the matrix multiplication himself.

Comment: @user702846, I believe your issue arrises due to the dimensions of `r` being 1x1 rather than being 2x1. Unfortunately, after fixing this, the system becomes exactly singular. Also, it appears that you require x_1+x_2+x_3=4.26 and -(x_1+x_2+x_3)=-1.73, which can not be.

Comment: @Max These numbers and matrices works finely in matlab and the answer is 3x1 vector.

Comment: @user702846, What solution does MatLab give you?

Comment: @max I added the matlab code. the final results is stored in beta.

Comment: @user702846, It looks like you're solving different problems in R and MatLab. In MatLab, you only have inequality constraints. In R, you only have equality constraints. Remember that in R, your constraints look like `b <= Ax <= b + r`, so by setting `r=c(0,0)`, you are forcing x_1+x_2+x_3=4.26 and -(x_1+x_2+x_3)=-1.73.

Comment: @max good point ! do you know other function/package in R which are able to function as matlab does ?!

Comment: @user702846, You should be able to swap your `b` and `r` in some way, right? You may have to play with your `b` value a bit.

Comment: @user702836, try this: `library(kernlab); H <- rbind(c(1,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(0,0,1)); f = rbind(0,0,0); A = rbind(c(1,1,1), c(-1,-1,-1)); b = c(-5,-5); r = rbind(5+4.26, 5-1.73); LB = rbind(0,0,0); UB = rbind(100,100,100); ipop(f,H,A,b,LB,UB,r)`

Comment: it works ! wow ... but it looks like you have shifted a little bit the system by 5 ? what is the role of 5 or how did you figure out ?! can you make it a bit more clear in your answer please ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original question asks about the error message *Error in crossprod(r, q) : non-conformable arguments*. The answer is that `r` must be specified with the same dimensions as `b`. So if `b` is 2x1 then `r` must also be 2x1.

A secondary question (from the comments) asks about why the system presented in the original question works in Matlab but not in R. The answer is that R and Matlab specify the problems differently. Matlab allows for inequality constraints to be entered separately from the equality constraints. However in R the constraints must all be of the form `b<=Ax<=b+r` (at least within the `kernlab` function `ipop`). So how may we mimic the original inequality constraints? The simple way is to make `b` very negative and to make `r'=-b+r`, where `r'` is your new `r` vector. Now we still have the same upper bound on the constraints because `r'+b=-b+r+b=r`. However we have put a lower bound on the constraints, too. My suggestion is to try solving the system with a few different values for `b` to see if the solution is consistent.

EDIT:

This is probably a better way to handle solving the program:

```
library(quadprog);  
dvec <- -f;  
Dmat <- H;  
Amat <- -t(A);  
bvec <- -rbind(4.26,-1.73);  
solve.QP(Dmat, dvec, Amat, bvec)
```

where these definitions depend on the previously defined R code.

Comment: I checked the answer considering different b and the result looks consistent !

Comment: the new code doesn't work if H is a fully zero matrix ! it complains that H is not positive definite, although it works under matlab !

Comment: @user702846, There's no reason why you can't continue to use the other code. The `solve.QP` function must make use of the fact that `H` is positive definite to solve the program. I'm looking at more options for solving quadratic programs.